# php imagick, how to make an area transparent

Tags: php, imagemagick, transparency, imagick

I want to make an area transparent within an Imagick object with a specific width, height  and a top position.

For example I need a transparent area with 30px x 30px from the 15th px to the top but I can't find a way to do it.

```
$canvas1 = new Imagick();

$canvas1->newImage(30,60,'black','png');
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the opacity as follows

```
$image->setImageOpacity(0.0);
```

If you set it to 0.0 the image what you have crated will become transparent

for more information you can [Set opacity in Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageopacity.php)

if you want it for a particular area  part then you need to change the approach by using GD library functions by doing some what like this

```
 $img = imagecreatefrompng($imgPath); // load the image
 list($width,$height) = getimagesize($imgPath); // get its size
 $c = imagecolortransparent($img,imagecolorallocate($img,255,1,254)); // create      transparent color, (255,1,254) is a color that won't likely occur in your image
 $border = 10;
 imagefilledrectangle($img, $border, $border, $width-$border, $height-$border, $c); // draw transparent box
 imagepng($img,'after.png'); // save
```

I Could see a similar requirement which is posted in another [forum here](http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=98527)

Comment: but I don't want to be transparent of all imagick object, only for an area

Comment: for example the imagick object I've given in the question has 30px of width and 60px of height and I want a transparent area with 30px of width and 30px of height at the bottom @UmairIqbal

Comment: I think you are creating images using imagick try using core GD functions so that lot more flexibility you get

Answer (score 3):

This may be a slightly simpler way of doing it. I recycled @AndreKR's setup code to get started:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->newImage(100,100, 'red');
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_ACTIVATE); // make sure it has an alpha channel
$box=$im->getImageRegion(30,30,15,15);
$box->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_TRANSPARENT);
$im->compositeImage($box,Imagick::COMPOSITE_REPLACE,15,15);
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can **flood fill** with transparency ink (not *transparent* ink) like this:

```
$im->floodFillPaintImage('#FF000000', 10, '#FFFFFF', 0, 0, false);
```

in [this post](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?p=27002#p27002), Anthony, apparently some important figure in the ImageMagick universe, says that you cannot **draw** with transparency.

So it seems you have to create a punch image and then use it to punch the transparent areas out in your actual image. To create the punch here I draw the rectangle opaque on a transparent brackground and then invert the whole image:

```
$punch = new Imagick();
$punch->newImage(100,100, 'transparent');
$drawing = new ImagickDraw();
$drawing->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel('black'));
$drawing->rectangle(15, 15, 45, 45);
$punch->drawImage($drawing);
$punch->negateImage(true, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
```

[image: punch]

Here's the actual image before the punching:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->newImage(100,100, 'red');
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_ACTIVATE); // make sure it has
                                                           // an alpha channel
```

[image]

Now we can copy over the alpha channel from our punch image. For a reason unknown to me the obvious way does not work:

```
// Copy over the alpha channel from one image to the other

// this does NOT work, the $channel parameter seems to be useless:
// $im->compositeImage($punch, Imagick::COMPOSITE_SRC, 0, 0, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
```

[image: unsuccessful result]

However, these both work:

```
// Copy over the alpha channel from one image to the other

// $im->compositeImage($punch, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);
// $im->compositeImage($punch, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0);
```

[image: result]

(The light blue is the background of the Windows photo viewer, indicating transparent areas.)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$canvas1->setImageOpacity(0);
```